# How do I take a lambda expression as a parameter that returns a method?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda

I want to be able to do this:

```
var test = SomeMethod(s => s.SomeMethod);
```

I can make it work with properties by making the method signature look like this:

```
SomeMethod<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
```

How can I make it work with methods? I know this is simple, I'm just missing something small.

Comment: What's the type signature of `s.SomeMethod`?

Comment: What the hell are you trying to do? :) I'm curious to see the answers...

Comment: what he is trying to do is something like `Func<Action<T>>`

Comment: I'm toying with an idea I had for implementing a fluent security interface for WCF on our intranet... but I need to be able to specify SecurityFor(myservice => myservice.Delete)

Comment: It needs to work kind of like FluentValidation where you say "RuleFor(vm => vm.Name)" except I need to work with methods.

Comment: @Max, this is a pretty neat idea, but I don't know if its useful the way you want to use it.

Comment: It will be made to work with our current infrastructure... it will be extremely useful if it's possible

Comment: @Stan R. - Func<Action<T>> doesn't seem to help, but I could be using it wrong... I'll play with that some more.

Comment: @Max, i am playing around with it..see my answer, to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq approaches this by requiring the method parameters to be stubbed out with special 'marker' objects like:

```
test.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>()));
```

Incidentally, this allows Moq to resolve method overloads (a single method name is ambiguous if you don't have any notion of the required parameters.)  They are going a bit further and using it to actually match parameters based on criteria, for the purpose of mocking objects for unit testing.  The [source code is available](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/checkout) and might give you some ideas.  They do all sorts of fun trickery with expression trees.

---

Here is an example based on the Moq source (hacked out a bit, but shows how the method can be extracted from the expression):

```
    internal static void ExtractMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
        where T : class
    {
            var methodCall = expression.ToMethodCall();
            var method = methodCall.Method;
            var args = methodCall.Arguments.ToArray();
    }
```

Straight from Moq source:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Casts the body of the lambda expression to a <see cref="MethodCallExpression"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">If the body is not a method call.</exception>
    public static MethodCallExpression ToMethodCall(this LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        Guard.NotNull(() => expression, expression);

        var methodCall = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCall == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                Resources.SetupNotMethod,
                expression.ToStringFixed()));
        }

        return methodCall;
    }
```

This will work with your code, but you'd have to pass 'dummy' parameters to allow the compiler to create the expression.  So if you had:

```
public void SomeMethod(int value, string text) {}
```

Then you'd pass it as:

```
ExtractMethod(s => s.SomeMethod(0, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
DoSomethingWithAction<T>(Func<T, Action> actionRetriever) { }
DoSomethingWithFunction<T, TResult>(Func<T, Func<TResult>> functionRetriever) { }
```

You would call these like:

```
DoSomethingWithAction<ObjectWithMethod>(obj => obj.Method);
DoSomethingWithFunction<ObjectWithProperty>(obj => obj.Property);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    public SimpleCommand( Predicate<object> canExecuteDelegate, Action<object> executeDelegate )
    {
        CanExecuteDelegate = canExecuteDelegate;
        ExecuteDelegate = executeDelegate;
    }
```

You will need to specify the function signature using Predicate or Action.

Comment: Definitely not the first parameter, because Predicate returns true or false... I don't think the second one works unless I"m doing it wrong...

In my SomeMethod method I need to be able to access information about the method itself that was passed in.

Comment: I missed that part then.  So you need an expression to get the name of the function (or some other thing)?

Comment: Yeah, basically I need the name... and information about the parameters it takes if possible (not necessary though atm)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        public class Test
        {
            public bool SomeMethod(string test)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Test testObj = new Test();


            Func<string, bool> rule1 = AddRule(testObj, x => x.SomeMethod);

            bool rsult = rule1("ttt");

        }

        static Func<string, bool> AddRule<T>( T obj, Func<T,Func<string, bool>> func)
        {
            return func(obj);
        }


}
```

Comment: This way of doing it requires me to know the method signature, correct? That isn't a possibility.

Comment: yeah, there is no way without knowing the method signature as they could be an infinite possibilities.

Comment: There has to be a way... even if it isn't quite as clean... maybe I can pass a delegate type as a generic parameter... hmm

Comment: I guess that wouldn't be any different from knowing the types

Comment: I find it hard to believe there isn't a way around this... I don't want to resort to magic strings... SecurityFor("Delete")... I guess I could just use T4 to generate constants or something like that... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's no way of doing this without specifying the method signature: Just think of overloaded methods:

```
void SomeMethod() { }
int SomeMethod(int a, int b) { return 0; }

// ...

var test = TestMethod(s => s.SomeMethod);
```

How would the compiler possibly know, which of the methods you want to test?